# What is the advantage of defining public functions that only call a private function

Tags: c++

I was reading some code written by one of my professors a while back, and I noticed he has this practice of never using a public function from within the encapsulating class. Even if the public function is a one-liner whose only job is simply to pass the arguments to a private function. So all of his classes look something like this

```
class A{
public:
    void do_work(Some_object& obj){
        m_do_work(obj);
    }

private:
   void m_do_work(Some_object& obj){
        // actual work is done here
   }

};
```

This seems like a waste of both development time and running time since that extra level of indirection has it's overhead. So what is the actual benefit of this style?

Comment: Maybe ask the author of the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am no longer in contact with him.

Comment: With optimization enabled, *"waste of [..] running time"* is wrong.

Comment: Don't he use pimpl idiom, and so `void do_work(Some_object& obj){
        mImpl->do_work(obj);
    }` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 no, nothing like that.

Comment: Why the downvote? I merely ask to see if there are benefits to this style that I should be aware of as a prospective software developer. If you think the style is indeed a waste, then please vote to close the question instead of downvoting which implies that this is a poor question to ask.

Comment: At first sight this doesn't make any sense to me. Is this c&p code or did you write it down from your memories. If the private function was protected instead (and functions where virtual), this could have been perhaps an [template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) implementation. The way you posted it, it seems to be a quite useless indirection (anyone correct me if I'm wrong please).

Comment: @andreee Indeed, he does have a couple of private virtuals following the same style. Those I was able to recognize as him strongly following the Template Method pattern on my own so I didn't feel necessarily to post that in the question. It was using it with regular (nonvirtual) functions that got me curious.

Answer (score 0):

A public function is a public interface and defines the way the users of your class view your class.

Your professor is hiding the details of the implementation in a private function and with that extra level of indirection he is probably intending to retain the original implementation of the public function while altering only the internals of the private function at a later time.
It's making things more modular at the expense of performance.

Pedagogic examples aside a decision would have to be taken by profiling performance if such calls affect the critical path of your application.

Comment: I'm skeptical that there would be additional indirection. An optimizing compiler would almost certainly elide the extra function call entirely. In fact, [GCC does](https://godbolt.org/z/nJlyFg).  I also don't understand how this hides any implementation details whatsoever. The body of a function is not part of its public interface. Unless the PIMPL idiom is being used, the extra private method does not make anything more modular.

Comment: I'm talking about the indirection introduced in the code not how the compiler behaves

Comment: Nothing that you say makes any sense. I didn't say that the body of a function is part of its public interface and I'm sure the C++ standards committee has no intention of changing the definition of what the private idiom is

Answer (score 0):

I once have done that to call the private function both inside and outside of the class. Since my public function had to lock a mutex before calling this function and my private not, it was useful. It was something like that;

```
public:
    void set_configuration()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m);
        reconfigure_output();
    }

private:
    void reconfigure_output()
    {
        ...
    }
    void some_other_function()
    {
        ...
        reconfigure_output();
    }
```

Comment: but you were doing more then merely calling the private function. Here it is not the case. But private parts are private, and even they are ugly there's nothing to be ashame of as long as they are not exposed :)